# SVN merge with sencha 2.2 extjs 4.2.x

Tags: svn, extjs4, sencha-architect

I have a big problem. I want to use SVN to work on the same project with my colleagues but i didn't success to implement it.
I have success to implement the repositery. So , when i update my files ans i check on my browser, i have the good result ( commit of my colleagues and modifs by me) . But my  xds file is not updated ( file generated by sencha architect 2.2). So , my question is , how to have a xds file up to date when my i do an update of my colleague commit's ?

thanks you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ok . You just have to merge the metadata folder who is generated by Architect and all will be fine :) .  Hope that will be usefull for other people .

++